# Ruby Conditioning between tables

Tags: sql, ruby

I have 2 tables:

Feedback : faceid (as int), Poolid (as int), deleted (as boolean)

Pool: id (as int), canceled (as boolean)

there is no DB integration between the two tables what so ever except the fact some of the rows contains the same value (pool.id can be equal to feedback.poolid).

if i where to write my query in SQL it would be somthing like:

```
SELECT Pool.* , Feedback.* FROM Pool, Feedback WHERE faceid = params[:faceid] 
and deleted = 'f' and (Pool.id = Feedback.poolid and Pool.cancel = 'f')
```

what is the best (and parametrized) way to implement it?

Comment: This is Rails? Which version?

Comment: yes it is rails version 3.2.11
im trying to get all the pools that are not canceled (canceled = 'f' and not deleted (deleted = 'f') and the faceid from the feedback table is equal to a parameter given from the client side (e.g params[:faceid]
thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think the following wiil work:

```
 Pool.find_by_sql("select * from pools,feedbacks where pools.id = feedbacks.pool_id and cancelled = false and deleted = false and faceid = #{params[:faceid]}")
```

Comment: thank you, i adjusted the query a bit and it doesnt work, and suggestions? it sais 

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PoolController#player

@host = Pool.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM pools, feedbacks WHERE (pools.id = feedbacks.poolid) and (pools.cancel = false) and (feedbacks.deleted = false) and (feedbacks.faceid = #{params[:faceid]})")

Comment: sure was very helpful, you can see my final code how i used your code to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
@host = Pool.find_by_sql("SELECT pools.* FROM pools, feedbacks WHERE (pools.id = feedbacks.poolid) AND (pools.cancel = 'f') AND (feedbacks.deleted = 'f') AND (feedbacks.faceid = #{params[:faceid]})")
```

thank you all